# WPF C# CefSharp Navigate URL

Tags: c#, wpf, cefsharp

I want to navigate new link like VS in webbrowser control but i can't this with wpf.

This for ie;

```
WebBrowser.Navigate("http://www.bing.com");
```

How is it done with CefSharp in WPF?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In cefsharp, you can do it like

```
string navigateUrl = "http://www.bing.com";
ChromiumBrowser.Address = navigateUrl;   //navigates to the URL

//or use Reload method if you want to reload it 
ChromiumBrowser.Reload(true);
```

Comment: Thanks, Load(); What's the difference?

Comment: There are different overloaded methods i think for loading the urls or static html to chromium browser. In my scenario, I needed to reload the browser on some button events after the page had been loaded. Setting Address onload should do it for you